# is it possible to remove and upload .aspx pages through another page in the website

Tags: asp.net

my website is hosted on my university servers and they refuse to give me access to servers,

is it possible to create a web page that removes and adds (replaces) a webpage in my website root folder? and how ?

my website is asp.net webforms with c# code-behind.

Comment: (If it is, you may still be faced with a boot-strap problem: How do you get that page "in your website"?)

Answer (score 1):

You can, if your ASP.NET account has a write access to the folder. See [Is it possible to implement a self-updating ASP.NET web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802736/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-self-updating-asp-net-web-application)

I would try to find a file manager, similar to [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68901/Simple-Web-File-Manager), and copy it to your project folder.

Answer (score -1):

You can not change the aspx pages with a new aspx page. And obviously not in the root directory. If it is in another directory it is possible only when you have write and execute permission. You only have the option of adding deleting replacing aspx files through `ftp`.

Comment: but cant i use the same method used in uploading pictures in a sub folder

Comment: Yaa... But you only can upload in the permission folder right

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense as you clearly said that a change the aspx with a new aspx is not possible and only ftp is the option. "Refuse the access to servers " is too broad and can be either physical access, or remote connectivity, or a web based access, or ftp. So ftp might not be the only option. You're right, in case of a web based access a write permission will be required, but this means a change would be possible if write permission is there. Root/non-root folder is not important if write permission is set. So your comment neither clear nor correct.